# Error compiling Git via Home Brew

Tags: git, gcc, homebrew

Having problems compiling Git via Homebrew

Error: Failed executing: make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.6 install

I've deleted and reinstall Homebrew and also reinstalled Xcode 3.2.6

System:
Mac OS X 10.6.8

Any ideas what is going on?

Updated:

Here's the tail end of error trace. Not sure where else to look. Hope this helps.

```
referenced  from :
 " _libiconv",      referenced _reencode_stringfrom: 
_reencode_stringin  libgit.a(inutf8.o )libgit.a
( utf8.o )"
_libiconv_close " ," _libiconv_close",    referencedreferenced  from   _reencode_string infrom:
   :  
  libgit.a_reencode_string(  in  utf8.o    libgit.a_reencode_string( utf8.oin) 
libgit.a ()utf8.o)
   "  _libiconv_close " ,
  referenced    _reencode_string  from:in
  libgit.a( _reencode_string utf8.o )
ld in :   _reencode_string symbol(s) not found
 in libgit.a(utf8.o)
ld: symbol(slibgit.a) not( utf8.o)
found 
     _reencode_string in libgit.a(utf8.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: collect2: Undefinedld returned 1 exit status 
symbols:
  "ld returned 1 exit status_libiconv_open"
, referenced from:
      _reencode_string in libgit.a(utf8.o)
  "_libiconvcollect2: ", referencedld returned 1 exit status 
from:
      _reencode_string in libgit.a(utf8.o)
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _reencode_string in libgit.a(utf8.o)
      _reencode_string in libgit.a(utf8.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [git-daemon] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [git-fast-import] Error 1
make: *** [git-imap-send] Error 1
make: *** [git-shell] Error 1
==> Exit Status: 2
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/git.rb#L37
==> Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8
HEAD: 63da621a3fb430cb9ae757a09077890be8aa689e
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
Hardware: quad-core 64-bit arrandale
OS X: 10.6.8
Kernel Architecture: i386
Ruby: 1.8.7-174
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Xcode: 3.2.6
GCC-4.0: build 5494 
GCC-4.2: build 5666 
LLVM: build 2335 
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11 installed? true
==> Build Flags
CC: /usr/bin/cc => /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
CXX: /usr/bin/c++ => /usr/bin/c++-4.2
LD: /usr/bin/cc => /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
CFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe
CXXFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe
MAKEFLAGS: -j4
```

Not sure if it's worth noting but the trace shows Ruby 1.8
while `ruby -v` gives a ruby 1.9.2p180

Okay I've updated the error trace.

Comment: No idea with what you posted. Please show more of the error message.

Comment: In error logs it is usually the first error that matters not the end of the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ld: symbol(s) not found` occurs either when you don't have a needed library dependency installed, or its inclusion or that of an object file is missing from the compile line for some reason.  Without knowing *what* symbols are not found, it's impossible to help further.  You cut off just at the good part of the error message.  It's like getting to the last chapter of a mystery novel and finding it ripped out :-)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by renaming the `lib` and `include` directories in `/usr/local` to `lib_old` and `include_old` and then running `brew install git` Unfortunately, this will likely break other code that depends on those directories...

Via this discussion: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/1948#issuecomment-326283